# Somar total de uma coluna com excelTableFilter

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma tabela que é retornada com o `while` e criei filtros na mesma com `excelTableFilter`. Agora ao filtrar na tabela pretendia que somasse o total da quantidade * o preço.

Código:

```
$tabela1 .= '<table border="5" class="teste1" method="POST" id="table">';
$tabela1 .='<thead>';
$tabela1 .= '<tr>';
$tabela1 .= '<th class="filter" style="width:42px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px">Quantidade</th>';
$tabela1 .= '<th class="filter" style="width:25px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px">Preço</th>';
$tabela1 .= '</tr>';
$tabela1 .='</thead>';
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {
$tabela1 .= '<tbody>';      
$tabela1 .= '<tr>';
$tabela1 .= '<td style="font-size: 12px"> '.$rows_cursos['Preco'].'</td>';
$tabela1 .= '<td style="font-size: 12px"> '.$rows_cursos['Quantidade'] * $rows_cursos['Preco'].'€</td>';
$tabela1 .= '</tr>';
}
```

Crio os filtros na tabela da seguinte forma:

```
$(function(){
    $('#table').excelTableFilter();
});
```

Pretendo que ao consultar por fatura dentro da tabela, no fundo da tabela mostrasse o valor total da soma da quantidade * preço do total das linhas retornadas.

Eu fiz isso em php, desta forma:

```
$Total = 0;
while($rows_cursos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_cursos)) {
$Total = $Total + ($rows_cursos['Quantidade'] * $rows_cursos['Preco']);
}

$tabela1 .= '<tr>';
$tabela1 .= '<td colspan="9" style="text-align: right;">';
$tabela1 .= '<strong>Valor Total:</strong> '. $Total .'€';
$tabela1 .= '</td>';
$tabela1 .= '</tr>';
```

Mas desta forma só funciona quando faço o filtro fora da tabela, quando faço o filtro dentro da tabela através da função que postei acima, o valor retornado é errado